# What is a Coulomb suppressed reaction?

Tags: cosmology, big-bang, coulombs-law, nucleosynthesis

I have specifically been reading the in context of Big Bang Nucleosynthesis however, I feel the concept is more general.

I could not find a definition online, I am just not sure what it means.

Many thanks.

Comment: I suspect it refers to a nuclear interaction between like charged entities that is suppressed by Coulpmb repulsion at low temperatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about the suppression effect of the Coulomb (i.e., electric force) force between two positively charged nucleus in a nuclear interaction. It tends to lower the effective nuclear reaction cross sections, as equally charged nucleus repel each other by the Coulomb force.

For high enough energies it can lower the overall nuclear cross section some, but still allow the reactions to take place. For low energies the cross section is lowered exponentially as getting through the Coulomb barrier involves quantum tunneling or the statistical fluctuations of particle energies where some will exceed the potential barrier. You can still calculate how much it ocurs and account for it.

It important in Big Bang nucleosynthesis and in stellar reactions. Important in figuring out the amount of lithium formed, and other nucleosynthesis products. See an intro to the topic at [this book excerpt.](https://books.google.gr/books?id=0VIpJPn-qWoC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=coulomb%20suppressed%20nuclear%20reaction&source=bl&ots=Hw1jTVCROG&sig=0BK2Iqyvix45UJ2GdCCT1dYNbXo&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=coulomb%20suppressed%20nuclear%20reaction&f=false)